# Возможно ли обновить форум IPB?

Tags: php

Имеется форум на движке IPB. Его версия 3.0.4, хотелось бы обновить его до 3.1.4. Возможно ли это сделать без переустановки и потери пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, конечно, главное бэкап сделать :)

**Дополнено.**

Делаем:

1. Бэкап всех файлов форума.
2. Делаем бэкап базы данных форума.
3. Скачиваем 3.1.4.
4. Внутри будет файлик как провести обновление, обычно это залить файлы из папки upload в папку с форумом и открыть /admin/upgrade/index.php.

Comment: Как?Что для этого требуется?

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас попробую

Comment: Ну что, как оно :)

Comment: Не получилось

Comment: Что не так пошло?